# Install a Wordpress Backup (Installatron tar.gz) on localhost

Tags: wordpress, installation, recovery

Is it possible to download an Installatron tar.gz Wordpress backup onto a localhost WAMP server and get a copy of website running locally using this method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some backup plugin like [duplicator](https://tah.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to clone the site and install it anywhere.